# MySQL Check for 3 or more consecutive entries

Tags: php, mysql

I have a live chat and i need to ban if the users chatted more than 5 times in a row

this is the sql:

```
function countMessages() {
        global $tsUser;
        $querys = db_exec(array(__FILE__, __LINE__), 'query', 'SELECT * FROM c_chat_messages where msg_user = "'.$tsUser->uid.'" ORDER BY msg_id ASC');
        $counts = db_exec('num_rows', $querys);
        if($counts > 5) { $this->banUser(); }
}
```

$tsUser->uid is the id of the user

i need to check if the user chatted for more than 5 times in a row so the php executes the  $this->banUser(); function

Comment: user can not chat more than 5 times in a row with another user or all over the chat community??

Comment: the user cant send 5 messages in a row in less than 15 seconds

Comment: With that kind of query, you select just one side of the conversation. If 2 people talk fast enough, it will look like spamming. Your algorithm should probably consider how the users alter while they fill the message table.

Answer (score 0):

you have to take `timestamp` of each message sent by the user in your database table.
And than you can fire a query checking if the user has sent more than 5 messages in last 15 seconds, by calculating the time different between the messages.

to get last five messages sent by that user,

```
SELECT * FROM c_chat_messages where msg_user = "'.$tsUser->uid.'" ORDER BY msg_id DESC limit 0,5
```

than get the difference between `last and first record returned by above query`.

to get time difference in seconds you can use

```
SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF('2010-08-20 12:01:00', '2010-08-20 12:00:00')) diff;
```

you can call a ajax file every one or two seconds to check this.

Let me know if further clarification needed.

Comment: I don't think this satisfies the brief

Comment: @Strawberry yeah, I know.. This is just a startup logic for the questioner. .